# Is zero forcing Optimization technique or Equalization technique?

Tags: digital-communications

I got some problem in the equalization techniques. I am new to communication simulations but I have done some data analysis labs in my college. I read some where on Internet that in a research paper that 
zero forcing is Optimization technique but on Wikipedia it says it is Equalization technique?

I am confused in equalization and optimization techniques in communication. I am doing a OFDM simulation project in MATLAB and I am stuck in terms of these. I have read on Google but they both terms are kind confusing

Can some body please explain the different equalization techniques and the use of zero forcing? 
Why to use zero forcing and what are basic possible equalization techniques that can be used with zero forcing.

Answer (score 6):

Zero-forcing is not an optimiziation technique and neither an equalization technique. It is simply one of several possible *criteria* to design (or optimize) an equalizer. A zero-forcing equalizer is designed to completely remove intersymbol interference, but does not take noise into account. Another, more practical criterion is the MSE (mean-square error) criterion, which results in an equalizer that minimizes intersymbol interference and reduces noise power at the same time.

I would suggest you consult one of the many good books on digital communication to learn more about this quite complex topic. Here are just two which I like:

- Digital Communication by Lee and Messerschmitt
- Digital Communications by Proakis

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt. Do you have some coding reference? I surely buy copy of this, Did any book contain coding simulation examples to better understand?

Comment: I don't have a code, and the books I mentioned don't have code either but explain the principle. If you understand the principle, then you can code it yourself. The subject is quite complex because you have several different equalizer structures (fractionally space, decision-feedback), even for the same criterion. In practice you'll need an adaptive equalizer, but I hope that your project has a limited scope and a clear definition of what you need to do.